# Can I view in which mode I am while using vi-mode for terminal (xterm)?

Tags: bash, terminal, vi, readline, xterm

The question is pretty self explanatory. I've heard from a co-worker there is a way to view in which mode I currently am when using vi-mode in terminal but somehow he forgot how it's done and I couldn't find an answer to that question. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a readline feature. To enable it, you have to set

```
set show-mode-in-prompt on
```

in your `~/.inputrc` file. This requires readline 6.3 or newer (bundled with Bash 4.3 or newer).

In vi mode, the mode strings then default to `(ins)` and `(cmd)`:

```
(cmd)$
(ins)$
```

This assumes that your prompt is simply `PS1='\$ '`.

You can customize them with two other readline settings, for example

```
set vi-cmd-mode-string [c]
set vi-ins-mode-string [i]
```

resulting in

```
[c]$
[i]$
```

Notice that non-printing characters (like terminal escapes for colours) have to be escaped with `\1` and `\2`. These two settings require readline 7.0 or newer (bundled with Bash 4.4 or newer).

Manual entries:

- [`show-mode-in-prompt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-show_002dmode_002din_002dprompt)
- [`vi-cmd-mode-string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-vi_002dcmd_002dmode_002dstring)
- [`vi-ins-mode-string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-vi_002dins_002dmode_002dstring)